# Access SharePoint subsite from different url

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, iis, alternate-access-mapping, dns

I want to access my SharePoint subsite from another url like my subsite url is http://abc/subsite1 and i want to access this **subsite** using this http://xyzdomain.com url. Is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this yet, but i am pretty sure that adding a CNAME for that subsite URL might work well.